# Rails: Insert a lot of HTML code through migration to the database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration

So here is the question: how can I insert a lot of HTML code(about 200 lines of code) to the database using migration?
I tried to do that:

```
class AddManyruToPages < ActiveRecord::Migration
include ActionView::Helpers
def up
      Page.create(
      slug:'manyru',
      content:
      <<-HTML
      <div class="manyru-wrapper">
        <div class="many-header">
          <div class="many-content">
            <div class="logo">
            #{image_tag "/images/manyru/many-logo.png"}
            </div>                  
          </div>                     
         </div>
      </div>
      HTML
      )
end

def down
      Page.find_by_slug('manyru').destroy
end
end
```

but it didn't work. The only thing I know is that after inserting immediately happens rollback and I don't know why?
If I should add more information, please tell.

Answer (score 1):

Rollback usually means that Your `create` method failed because of validations specified on Your model.

Assign result to some variable:

```
p = Page.create ...
```

And then inspect errors:

```
puts p.errors.full_messages.inspect
```

Comment: Sorry for delay Edgars. I did like you said but it shows me only this: undefined local variable or method `config' and I think the problem lies in 'image_tag' helper in my code. What do you think?

Comment: I need to see inside the HTML then and know where was the error.

Comment: And I've just found that I even can't use image_tag in a rails console. The same error. Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Helper works only if write 'image_tag("")'. This is a little weird

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, try calling helper directly without including the module, like this: `ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("manyru/many-logo.png")`

Also skip the images folders when specifying path, assets libs should take into account.

Comment: After a bit of searching, I've decided that the easiest way is the best way and just replaced all the helpers on a simple html code (<img src =' path',etc) and it works! But anyway, thank you for your time.